# GIF: two different monitor looks gif very different

Tags: colors, profile, gif, srgb

I've 2 pc with windows 7
I've two monitor, same brand, same model
2 pc aare using the same browser: ie8

With first pc i see one web page we make with all color ok

In the second pc, some of the gif looks like differents

This gif have built-in sRGB and GIMP says me that ther're indexed, so I think it'S impossibile THEY LOOK LIKE DIFFERENT in different pc...

I open Photoshop, I assign sRGB, save and the image is IDENTICAL (SVN tell me no difference)

What can be the problem ?

I'm not a graphic expert, i'm a php programmer, but the client has this problem ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have a screen calibration problem. See for instance http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/